# How to process categorical variable having lots of unique values in linear regression?

Tags: regression, data-mining, linear-regression, data-cleaning

I have House Price dataset and I am using linear regression to predict the house price.

while data preprocessing I found a variable called "Location" and it have around 342 unique value. For performing regression I have to convert this Location variable to numerical value.

**So how do I handle this "Location" variable? or will it be fine to delete this variable?**

Comment: Try searching the Internet/SE for "Handling high-cardinality Categorical features"

Comment: **So how do I handle this "Location" variable?** For categorical features with such high cardinality you can check the distribution of those value, i.e check if for example from those 350 categories, 5 have the 80% of the presence, so It would be wise to group the remaining 345 in mi example) as others. In this way you reduce drastically the sparcity when one hot encoding the feature.                                                    **will it be fine to delete this variable?**  Yes if this have no predictive power for your model